# De facto way to add subdomains (like the jp in jp.sweet-website.org) for nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, subdomain

Express is at version 4.10.2 and Node is at version 6.5.0

What is a solution for creating a subdomain on my site?

I have a site where I'd like to add a japanese-facing version to be accessible by

`http://jp.site-in-question.run`

in addition to the default english homepage at

`http://site-in-question.run`

I have looked at some packages and will update this question as I delve into it.  Any help before I go too far down the rabbit hole is appreciated! =)

Answer (score 1):

This is called virtual hosting. There is no built-in handling of virtual hosts in Express.js, but there's an additional middleware you can use: [vhost](https://github.com/expressjs/vhost).

Otherwise, you can do it yourself by checking the value of the "Host" HTTP header the request.

Comment: Oh I was not aware of the "Host" field in the http-header.  That's a very helpful thing to know.  Thank you for pointing that out.